# Determine branch point from Github Webhooks & .git/

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to track the history of a repo on Github as it's created. Tracking a linear history is simple enough with the `PushEvent`, but I'd also like to track branches, merges, etc.

From playing around with it so far, it seems like a `PushEvent`'s `before` field only gives you the previous commit on the `ref` that was pushed, so if you create a branch called `test` and push to it, the previous commit is `000000` since there was no previous commit on `test`. The `CreateEvent` only tells you that a branch was created, but it doesn't seem to tell you what the branch point was.

From what I can tell, the only way to get around this is to pull the repo and crawl `.git/` to reconstruct the full history DAG. Is that correct, or is there another kind of event that I should be looking into?

Also, if I'm trying to recreate the history from `.git/`, `logs/refs/head/{branch name}` only gives you something like this:

> `3e0bad...` `3e6422...` `{Author}` `1458238937 -0700` merge `test`: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.

This doesn't tell you which commit was merged with `3e0bad...` to create the merge commit. Is the only way to do it to go to `logs/refs/head/test` and look at the latest commit before the timestamp `1458238937`, or is there somewhere else that the parent commits are stored explicitly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information really isn't available.

Consider, for instance, the following sequence of commands:

```
$ git clone <url> repo
$ cd repo
$ git checkout -b b1 master
Switched to a new branch 'b1'
$ echo stuff >> file; git add file; git commit -m add-stuff
[b1 b100000] add-stuff
...
$ git checkout -b b2
Switched to a new branch 'b2'
$ echo more stuff >> file; git add file; git commit -m more-stuff
[b2 b200000] more stuff
...
$ git push origin b2
```

Note that I'm not pushing `b1` here.

At this point, `origin` (whether github or any other site) receives, from us:

- commit `b100000...` (this hash is made up of course; the name starting with `b1` is meant to tell *us* that `b1` was created "from" master using branch `b1`);
- commit `b200000...`;
- any trees and/or file blobs needed for those two commits (presumably updated trees and blobs for file `file`, although it's possible, however unlikely, that the required tree and file blobs are already present due to the new trees and files matching some existing trees and files); and
- a request to set `refs/heads/b2` to `b200000...`.

The new commits have the usual metadata: commit `b100000...` has whatever `master` pointed-to as its parent, and `b200000...` has `b100000...` as its parent.  Let's assume that `master` has not moved since the clone, and call its commit `a000000...`.

Presumably neither `b1` nor `b2` exist on the server.  The server's hook therefore gets an update that creates `refs/heads/b2` pointing to `b200000...`, i.e., the "old" SHA-1 is the null hash.

If, on the server, we accept this push, and then look at the resulting commit graph, we'll see `b2` pointing to `b200000...`, which points to `b100000...`, which points to `a000000...`, which is on an existing branch, `master`.  We will then conclude that branch `b2` was created directly from master.

But it wasn't!

If I now `git push origin b1`, I will send no objects (`origin` already has everything needed) and a request to set `refs/heads/b1` to `b100000...`.  This will be another branch creation in the hook, but this time `b1` is being created pointing to a commit that's already on branch `b2`.  Where shall we now decide that `b1` was created from?

> Also, if I'm trying to recreate the history from [a reflog, and I encounter a merge ...]

The commit that was current before the merge occurred is always the first parent of the merge commit itself.  The merged-in commit is, in the graph, identified by the 2nd (or in the case of an octopus merge, 3rd, 4th, etc) parent of the merge.  As you have seen, the text in the reflog contains the argument presented to `git merge`, which *may* be a branch name, or a tag name, or indeed anything acceptable to `git rev-parse` (see [the `gitrevisions` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html)).

Comment: Thanks, torek! I spent a little bit of time digging through the git source, and it's not completely clear how they reconstruct history. e.g., when you type `git log`, it shows that a certain merge commit is the merge of two (or more) commits. Where does that information come from?

Comment: Parentage is stored directly in the commit object itself.  Use `git cat-file -p <obj-id>` to view objects (this converts tree objects to text format, while the remaining objects merely need decompression).  Commits have a series of header lines for internal metadata, then a blank line, then your log message.  The internal data for a commit includes its parent IDs.  (Normally you're best off running git "plumbing" commands to extract this sort of data, e.g., `git rev-parse` to get IDs, `git ls-tree`, and so on.)